# Xcode7 synthesize setter settableview for null resettable property does not handle nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode7

In iOS9 I get the warning

[image]

This is on a UITableViewController.

Although everything works fine, I would just like to actually understand the meaning of this warning.

So the setter does not handle when tableView is set to nil.

I can override the setter to get rid of the warning, but is there a better way to go about this? or should I not have synthesised a built in property in the first place?

```
- (void)setTableView:(UITableView *)inTableView
{
    if (!inTableView) {
        return;
    }
    [super setTableView:inTableView];
}
```

Comment: Do you plan to use your Objective-C code from Swift?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, I don't quite understand your question or see how this relates to Swift?

Comment: The whole annotation stuff relates to Swift and is in Objective-C pointless.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options to implement a `null_resettable` property:

1. Check for a nil param in the setter and set to a default value.
2. Create a getter that lazy creates a default value if the current value is nil.

Do either of these things and the warning will go away.